# Styling html content using Jquery's css("property","style") method

Tags: jquery

I've just started Jquery and I'm stuck on this. I want to change the color of this text when the button gets clicked. Here is the code,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
  $("h3").css('background-color','red');
 });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h3>Click to change me</h3>
<input type="button" value="click Me"/>
```

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

**Edit:** I just separated the jquery src and jquery type in another line and the code started working

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a button element. When using `"input[type=button]"` as selector your code works fine. However you probably want to specify your selectors a bit more by class or by id.

Also changed `background-color` css property to `color` property to change the actual text instead of background.

Last changed the old fashioned `click()` function to more modern `on()`. Although this doesn't causes issues. The `on()` can be more efficient on memory and can be used for event delegation too. Although I don't think it's wrong to use the `click()` function, i think it's best practice to use the `on()` function.

```js
$("#MyColorChangingButton").on('click', function() {
  $("#ColorChangingElement").css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="ColorChangingElement">Click to change me</h3>
<input id="MyColorChangingButton" type="button" value="click Me" />
```

Comment: what about giving an id to button and do the rest. But this still not working.

Comment: @Rose I changed my snippet so it works with id's instead. I removed the ready event handler because it's not needed for SO snippets. You might want to add that again for your website.

Comment: this still not working, don't know why! Should I download the js file again?

Comment: @Rose If you mean the jQuery js file then no, you only need that once. Do you have any errors in your development console? As you can see in the snippet the problem is not in the code I posted. You either have no onload handler (For scripts that need it) or have other pieces of code that interfere.

Comment: I was using the single script tag with src and type tags in it, like this _<script src=" file.js" type=" text/javascript">_. I closed the script with the src tag only and created a new script with the type tag and added all the js code in it and it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in this line `$("button").click`, That's not how you select the button, either use this `$(":button")` or `$('input[type=button]')`. 
Try the code below

```
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=button]").click(function(){
        $("h3").css('background-color','red');


    })  ;
});

</script>
</head>
```

You can also give your button a class or an id & select using that which infact is a better approach.

Comment: this is not working, I tried with the $(":button") selector

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. You are giving background color and you are selecting button wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#buttonId').on('click', function() { 
       $('h3').css('color', 'red');
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Click to change me</h3>
<input type="button" value="click Me" id="buttonId"/>
```

Comment: why not using .click method?